# How to study for certificate B1 exam?

Tags: learning

I am a student from Delhi, India. My German language exam for certificate B1 is coming up very soon. My school teacher helped me with registration and all, but now she's taking my exam very lightly. I'm looking for some advice on how to properly study for the exam.

Comment: It would be helpful you describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: What is the name of the exam, which you will take?

Comment: This question may be more suited on [languagelearning.se]

Answer (score 5):

You could start by trying to solve the model papers available on Goethe institute website. Once you know your weak spots, you can then focus on making them better with grammar practice books. It may also help to read/listen to small extracts from German media.

Answer (score 2):

You did not tell much about yourself and your conditions of living and learning, but your question suggests you are in Delhi, and of course you seem to have internet access.

Here is a website that was designed especially for people who want to learn German on their own (self-learning):

[Ich-will-Deutsch-lernen / www.iwdl.de](https://www.iwdl.de/cms/lernen/start.html)

This is a programme run by the German adult education umbrella organisation *Deutscher Volkshochschulverband* (network of about 900 mostly municipal adult education centers all over Germany), in a project funded by the federal government. It is non-commercial, it is good quality, and using it is free.

You can register there with your e-mail account, and you can chose training material appropriate to your level, here B1.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search found me this:
http://www.gls-german-courses.de/2008.html

Go to B1 on this site and they have a sample exam.